# Linux Shell script - grep . filename

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

Can some explain the meaning of `grep . filename`, what does the <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) means here.?

Actually it removed all the empty lines in my file.
I just want to know how it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `grep` a dot is meant to be a regex so it stands for any character. If you want to `grep` occurrences of '.' you can use

```
grep '\.' filename
```

(or use `fgrep` which equals `grep -F`)

```
fgrep . filename
```

Note: If there is an empty line containing a space, it will be shown in the output of:

```
grep . filename
```

Why it does not match empty lines? Because there is no character in empty line between `^` and `$` (start and end of line). Empty lines-only grep is:

```
grep '^$' filename
```